# What is the correct way for redirecting from the domain name itself to a page in a directory?

Tags: asp.net, html, iis, redirect, iis-manager

I want anyone browsing for "MyDomain.com" to see what's in "MyDomain.com/Folder1/HomePage.aspx".

I tried adding a page with `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='MyDomain.com/Folder1/HomePage.aspx'" />` but there is a slight delay. I'd rather it is done silently.

I tried using iis-manager's HTTP-Redirect, but all sub-directories inherit it. (And asking here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13629137/prevent-subdirectories-from-inheriting-an-http-redirect-in-iis about solving that returned mainly silent close-votes.)

So how do I achieve it?

Comment: You can't keep the host name and omit the protocol in a URL. Does your `<meta>` redirect actually work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Response.Redirect
```

Seems to be the best way.

Answer (score 0):

Meta will take some time because it will first come to client, and then it will be transferred to the new page since HTML executes in browser - not on server.

The fastest method if to place use `Server.Transfer("~/Folder1/HomePage.aspx")` on your `Default.aspx` page. This will be executed on server as compared to `Response.Redirect` which also throws content back to browser first, then transfers to new page.

But the drawback of using `Server.Transfer("~/Folder1/HomePage.aspx")` is that it will not change the URL of the browser. I mean even you will be sitting on "MyDomain.com/Folder1/HomePage.aspx" but browser will be showing you the URL of previous page.

I hope this answers your question. If yes, then mark it as "answered".

Comment: Doesn't work. See my other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13633316/how-to-server-transfer-from-a-standalone-page

Answer (score 0):

What about trying something like this in the Default.aspx page load event?

```
Response.Status = "Redirecting"
Response.AddHeader("Location", "MyDomain.com/Folder1/HomePage.aspx")
```