# How to Server.Transfer from a standalone page?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-4.0

I have a page in a folder on a site, and I want to `Server.Transfer` to it from the domain root. I tried adding a page to the root containing:

```
Server.Transfer("~/folder1/default.aspx");
```

But I get a 500 error. I also tried

```
Server.Transfer("/folder1/default.aspx");
```

With the same result.
But when I tried `Server.Transfer("default2.aspx");` - another page in the root, it worked.

So how do I transfer to the page I want to transfer to?

EDIT: folder1 is a web application (Asp.net) - does it matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - it matters that folder1 is a separate application in its own right.

Server.Transfer is only meant for transfers within your own ASP.NET application as it directly instantiates the target page and sends the response back from where it was called.  It has no way of doing this across applications.

It will be better for you to perform a simple `Response.Redirect` to the /folder1/default.aspx page instead of transferring there.

Edit:  In the Page_Load of your Default.aspx (root), add

```
Response.Redirect("/folder1/Default.aspx");
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, that has a delay for the user. See my other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630820/what-is-the-correct-way-for-redirecting-from-the-domain-name-itself-to-a-page-in

Comment: An IIS redirect is different.  A `Response.Redirect` is something you would send from the codebehind of Default.aspx in the root.  So in the Page_Load event of the root's Default.aspx, do a Response.Redirect.